# Pandas add column based on grouped by rolling average

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have successfully added a new summed Volume column using Transform when **grouping by Date** like so:

```
 df

 Name   Date        Volume
 --------------------------
 APL    12-01-2017   1102
 BSC    12-01-2017   4500
 CDF    12-02-2017   5455

 df['vol_all_daily'] = df['Volume'].groupby([df['Date']]).transform('sum')

 Name   Date        Volume   vol_all_daily
 ------------------------------------------
 APL    12-01-2017   1102     5602
 BSC    12-01-2017   4500     5602
 CDF    12-02-2017   5455     5455
```

However when I want to take the rolling average it doesn't work!

```
df['vol_all_ma_2']=df['vol_all_daily'].
groupby([df['Date']]).rolling(window=2).mean()
```

Returns a DataGroupBy that gives error *and becomes too hard to put back into a df column anyways.

```
 df['vol_all_ma_2'] = 
 df['vol_all_daily'].groupby([df['Date']]).transform('mean').
 rolling(window=2).mean()
```

This just produces near identical result of vol_all_daily column

**Update:**

I wasn't taking the just one column per date..The above code will still take multiple dates...Instead I add the .first() to the groupby..Not sure why groupby isnt taking one row per date.

Comment: note bug in above code, where you make reference to undefined `res` (also `df` is not defined).  Please see [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Fixed...Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of what you have written seems correct (**Part 1** below), but perhaps you want to be calling something different (**Part 2** below).

**Part 1: Why what you have written is behaving correctly**:

```
d = {'Name':['APL', 'BSC', 'CDF'],'Date':pd.DatetimeIndex(['2017-12-01', '2017-12-01', '2017-12-02']),'Volume':[1102,4500,5455]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['vol_all_daily'] = df['Volume'].groupby([df['Date']]).transform('sum')
print(df)
rolling_vol = df['vol_all_daily'].groupby([df['Date']]).rolling(window=2).mean()
print('')
print(rolling_vol)
```

I get as output:

```
          Date Name  Volume  vol_all_daily
0 2017-12-01  APL    1102           5602
1 2017-12-01  BSC    4500           5602
2 2017-12-02  CDF    5455           5455

Date         
2017-12-01  0       NaN
            1    5602.0
2017-12-02  2       NaN
Name: vol_all_daily, dtype: float64
```

To understand why this result `rolling_vol` is correct, notice that you have first called the `groupby`, and only *after* that you have called `rolling`.  That should not produce something that fits with `df`.

**Part 2: What I think you wanted to call (just a rolling average)**:

If you instead run:

```
# same as above but without groupby
rolling_vol2 = df['vol_all_daily'].rolling(window=2).mean()
print('')
print(rolling_vol2)
```

You should get:

```
0       NaN
1    5602.0
2    5528.5
Name: vol_all_daily, dtype: float64
```

which looks more like the rolling average you seem to want.  To explain that, I suggest reading the details of [pandas resampling vs rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#stats-moments-ts-versus-resampling).

Comment: Its part I im having trouble with. The test data you made works, but my actual df  does not... My rolling_vol produces identical results to 'vol_all_daily'.  I dont know if this is some kind of indexing problem or Im overlooking something..When I type df.index I just get Int64Index([1,2....)..The sum results are perfect.

Comment: Ok I stand corrected..Both solutions (1 and 2) are not want I want..I do want rolling average just grouped by the date...I will rewrite my question expanding on your test data.